# Find what fails in a if statement

Tags: kotlin

I have the below code & want to use the condition that fails in my toast message. how do i do that without checking each if?

if(player1.isNullOrBlank() || player2.isNullOrBlank())
    Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter both player names",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a `when` expression here since you're going to have to check each condition regardless.

```
val errorMessage -> when {
    player1.isNullOrBlank() && player2.isNullOrBlank() -> "Please enter a name for both players"
    player1.isNullOrBlank() -> "Please enter a name for Player 1"
    player2.isNullOrBlank() -> "Please enter a name for Player 2"
    else -> null
}

if (errorMessage != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
} else {
    // success condition
}
```

Another example, using `also` instead of an assignment.

```
when {
    player1.isNullOrBlank() && player2.isNullOrBlank() -> "Please enter a name for both players"
    player1.isNullOrBlank() -> "Please enter a name for Player 1"
    player2.isNullOrBlank() -> "Please enter a name for Player 2"
    else -> null
}?.also { errorMessage ->
    Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks. This seems the simplest, given that there is no way to figure out what succeed & failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Logs:

```
Log.e("Player 1 Status", player1.isNullOrBlank() + "");
Log.e("Player 2 Status", player2.isNullOrBlank() + "");
```

And check the Red Log in your LogCat when you run it.

Comment: This does not preserve the `Toast.show()` from the question.

Comment: He is not even asking about Toast.show(). He is asking how to find what is failing inside the if statement. That's why I showed him how to Log the conditions he had.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
val nullPlayerNames = listOf("p1" to player1, "p2" to player2)
    .filter { (_, p) -> p.isNullOrBlank() }
    .joinToString(separator = ", ") { (tag, _) -> tag }
Toast.makeText(this, nullPlayerNames, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: Do not do that. Readability is paramount. Performance is good, too.

Answer (score -1):

Just write the code. Do not overthink this. Just check what you have to check and provide good error messages. The `||` operator does not output a side-track variable to check or anything like that. Just write the code.

```
if (player1.isNullOrBlank() && player2.isNullOrBlank()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter both player names", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
} else if(player1.isNullOrBlank()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter player name 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
} else if(player2.isNullOrBlank()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter player name 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Comment: use [when-expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression)

Comment: @IR42 How? There are two parts to the if. How do you make that a `when` expression?

Comment: How does that make any difference whatsoever and in what way does that answer the OP's question? It is not "without checking each if".

Comment: @gonutz: "Just write the code. We call this programming." There's no need for snark here. Help mentor new members; this comes across as condescending.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Right you are, snarkiness removed.